# iAd won't work when the banner is pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

I have seen other questions, but they don't seem to help...

I have an iAd banner at the bottom of one of my view controllers in my tab-bar app.
I would like to hide it when it doesn't have an advert, but reveal it when it does.

Here is my code from the View Controller for bringing it on or off, based on Apple's example:

```
- (void)configureAdAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect viewFrame   = self.mainView.frame;
    CGRect bannerFrame = adBannerView.frame;

    self.adBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

    if (adBannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        viewFrame.size.height -= adBannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = viewFrame.size.height;
        self.adIsVisible = YES;
    }
    else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = viewFrame.size.height + bannerFrame.origin.y;
        self.adIsVisible = NO;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        self.mainView.frame = viewFrame;
        [self.mainView layoutIfNeeded];
        adBannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];

}
```

It throws random errors every now and then (some unknown, some like "Ad inventory unavailable", etc.), and it goes off when it has to, but when it comes on I can't click on it and there is a black space above it, like so:

[image: iAd doesn't open, and the banner has a black space above it...]

I have set the current content size identifier, the delegate (= self), etc.

What should I do to make it work?
Please tell me if you need more code, more info etc.
Thank you!

Comment: there is a good video on how to deal with iAds see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350824/iad-on-webview-iphone/7794535#7794535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simplify the debugging by implementing iAd in a single view application instead of a tabbed layout.

Note that the black space appears to be the same size as an iAd.  This should give you a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: I had to remove "self.mainView.frame = viewFrame;" and "[self.mainView layoutIfNeeded];" Now it works!